# Postgresql switch query to function

Tags: postgresql, function, stored-procedures

This query works but i want to change it to function How i can do that when region is Varchar and woman and man are integer ?

```
Select region,man, woman,
Case
When woman > man then woman - man
When woman < man then man - woman
ELSE 0
END
AS test
FRom people;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just [make it one](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html):

```
create function ops()
  returns table (region varchar, man integer, woman integer, test integer)
as
$$
Select region,man, woman,
       Case 
         When woman > man then woman - man
         When woman < man then man - woman
        ELSE 0 
       END AS test
From people;
$$
language sql;
```